# Not able to use javascript variable in code behind in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Guys I am using a jquery price range slider for getting Price range from user.But the problem is that the Price range selected by user on slider I have to use that in code behind.My code is like this:
 My java script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        //adding load class to body and hide page
        document.documentElement.className += 'loadstate';
    </script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" >
      var str1=  document.getElementById("amt3").value;
     var str2=   document.getElementById("amt4").value;
     document.getElementById("hf1").value = str1;
     document.getElementById("hf2").value = str2;
    </script>

    </head>
```

My Html code is like this:

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hf1" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hf2" runat="server" />
    <div class="form-row row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <label class="form-label span4" for="slider">
                    Range slider</label>
                <div class="span8">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate >
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
                    <div id="slider-range"    class="slider" >
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" id="amount1" style="border: 0; color: #ED7A53; font-weight: bold;
                        box-shadow: none;" />
                    <input type="text" id="amt3"    style="border: 0; color: #ED7A53; font-weight: bold;
                        box-shadow: none;" />
                    <input type="text" id="amt4"    name="amt4" style="border: 0; color: #ED7A53;
                        font-weight: bold; box-shadow: none;" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and My code Behind is like this:

```
 protected void lnkFilter_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

          string str=  hf1.Value;
            if (WebHelper.Cast(amt2.Value, 0) != 0)
            {
                Fill();

            }


            }
```

But the Problem is hf1 (hidden field) is getting empty string value.Please help me in this and suggest me a solution how to use selected range on jquery slider in code behind file.

Comment: Are your ASP Hidden Fields in a page that uses a Master page? If so, their ID's get changed automatically when the page is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your hidden values inside your Update panel as they will not get posted back to the server on a partial update.